# Laravel different objects merge and sort

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, merge

I have two different objects with different columns in DB. Since I need to show both of those objects on timeline, I wanted to merge them and sort by date. Date column is not called the same so I am adding it within for loop.

```
public function index()
{
    $users = array_slice(WPUser::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get()->toArray(), 0, 20);

    // count = 80
    $comments = WPComment::with('recipe')->orderBy('comment_date', 'desc')->get()->toArray();
    foreach ($comments as &$comment) {
        $comment['date_time'] = $comment['comment_date'];
    }

    // count = 241
    $favorites = WPFavorite::with('user', 'recipe')->orderBy('date_time', 'desc')->get()->toArray();

    // count = 321
    $mergedArray = array_merge_recursive($comments, $favorites);

    $mergedArray = collect($mergedArray);
    $mergedArray = $mergedArray->sortByDesc('date_time');
    $mergedArray = $mergedArray->groupBy('date_time');

    return $mergedArray;

    //return view('dashboard.index', compact('users', 'mergedArray'));
}
```

The problem is that I can't get what I want. If I leave dates to be of default `Carbon` format, they seem to sort fine, but they will not group by day of course because of different `h:m:s`. If I however change that in both models:

```
public function getDateTimeAttribute($date)
{
    return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date)->format('d.m.Y.');
}
```

I am not getting it sorted right...

I tried by grouping the objects before even converting them to array which then gives me back sorted arrays, but such that I have first object sorted, and then merged to it below second object...

If I have both `Comment` and `Favorite` posted on same date (for example today), I want them both on top of my JSON file under '02.09.2016'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to solve your task with using function for modifying date_time before grouping. Try the following code:

```
$mergedArray = $mergedArray->groupBy(function($item)
{
    return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $item['date_time'])->format('d.m.Y.');
});
```

Comment: Jesus I have ben struggling with this for 2 days...you deserve a beer